# function that returns the number of digits in a string

Tags: python-2.7

Define a Python function called count_digits which receives as a parameter a string and returns the number of digits in the string.

As an example, the following code fragment:
print count_digits("ab1c2d34")
should produce the output:
4

Answer (score 3):

```
def count_digits(s):
    count = 0
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit():
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

s = 'ab1c2d34'    
count = len(re.findall(r'\d', s))

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def count_digits(s):
        return len(filter(lambda c: c.isdigit(), s))

>>> count_digits("ab1c2d34")
4
```

To use this solution in Python 3 you have to add a call to `list` around the filter function, because filter returns an iterator in Python 3. `list(filter(...))`

Comment: @pramttl Personally i don't like it since it uses lambda, and overall is much harder to understand. Readability counts and simple is better than complex.